# PLT[Racket/Scheme] Compound Interest + Accumulators -How to

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm fiddling another time with a (should be easy) task.

compound interest... (formula is known)
Scheme... (For one single years everything works flawlessy)

Problem: Accumulator needed...
My program has to be able to remember the result of the former calculation and put it as a blueprint for the next one following.

Here comes my question: How to setup accu-procedures without lists....?
Or am I deadly wrong for now, and I must use them?

Somehow I'll have to call the recursive procedure again and again...

Many thanks in advance,
sincerely, Andreas_P

Andreas_P

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question makes me a bit dizzy.  I have a bunch of answers for you, but I get the sense that *you're* not quite sure what your question is.

My real advice for you is a generous helping of [How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org). Specifically, you need to start at step one, and decide what your program takes in and produces, and write a one-line description of how the inputs are mapped to the outputs.

As always, apologies for any offense given.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
(define (fv n pv r)
  (if (= n 0)
      pv
      (fv (- n 1) (* pv (+ 1 r)) r)))
```

where the value of `pv` is replaced by the value at the end of the period, and the number of periods is reduced by one each recursion.

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) has good coverage of how to structure recursion --- it's worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your kind answers.

;;[No real DBC!]
;;CONTRACT: compound-interest: number number number -> number
;;PURPOSE: This function has to create a "compound interest" calculating method,
;;         when recursively calling the compound interest function up to x times again.
 
;;EXAMPLE: (compound-interest 1000 1.05 360) //Should produce 1050

(define (compound-interest capital interest-rate interest-time)
    (cond;
        [(interest-time >= 3600) capital];
        [else;
         (* interest-rate (compound-interest capital interest-rate (- interest-time 360)))];
      );
  );

(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 360) 2100 0.1);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 720) 2205 0.01);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 1080) 2315.25 0.001);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 1440) 2431.0125 0.0001);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 1800) 2552.563125 0.00001);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 2160) 2680.19128125 0.000001);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 2540) 2814.20084531 0.0000001);
(check-within (compound-interest 2000 1.05 2900) 2954.91088758 0.000000001);
;(compound-interest 2000 1.05 3260)
;(compound-interest 2000 1.05 3600)

At first you're correct I was on the wrong track... concerning accumulators or not...
then a fellow student explained me why and here is the result.

Well, [first commenter]: Yes it looks very similar, but because of it is SICP which was
planned for 6.001 MIT I couldn't make real use of, due to not having SICP correction module installed within DrRacket.

Well [second commenter]: probably you're right and I should go more into detail and 
read some more about "memory functions" within our faculty.

Last but not least, Thank you for your both answers and I for now feel be (somewhat) enlightened to solve and close this "thread".

Have a nice day... [geek folks]
Andreas_P

Answer (score 0):

```
;interest:number -> number
(define (interest x)
  (or(if(and(> x 0)(< x 1000))(* .04 x))(if(and(> x 1000)(< x 5000))(* .045 x))(if(> x 5000)(* .05 x))))
(interest 500)(* .04 500)
(interest 1600)(* .045 1600)
(interest 90000)(* .05 90000)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting an answer. Please consider adding context to your code.